# Using Tails as USB Wallet - Is it safe?

Tags: wallet, hardware-wallet

This Tails Tutorial by onehitwonder was recently posted in the [iota reddit](https://medium.com/@onehitwonder/creating-a-safe-environment-for-your-iota-wallet-and-seed-1fe5a563addb) and even [endorsed by a reddit iota mod](https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/7rmc55/psa_do_not_use_online_seed_generators/).

But did any dev or similar look over it, if its safe to use?

Would be great for the community to have an approved way to store your iota on a (kina) portable USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is safe but due to this not being an official script from the IOTA foundation it can be modified and changed to try and phish users.

Before running or downloading the script you should always check [the GitHub](https://github.com/onehitwonderos/safe-iota-wallet) for it and see if it has been modified for a malicious purpose.